# Compiling Large Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

Currently trying to update an app to iOS 10, and this is a very big app. It has over 20 libraries and over 50 Swift/Objective-C files. Although I converted most of the Swift Syntax to Swift 3, I still have many compiler errors, and Xcode is very slow to load them. I'm attempting to go to each file one by one and compiling them, but even that is taking a long time, and Xcode will still not show all the compiler errors.

First it'll show 2, then 8, then 46, then as soon as I fix one with "Fix-It", it'll go back down to 2. I have to re-compile every time for more errors to show up to fix, and this does not feel efficient.

How can I efficiently compile all the files to get all the compiler errors that I need to fix?

Comment: That's not a very big app.  Right now, you probably don't have many options for doing the conversion.

Comment: You say you are attempting to go to each file one by one to compile. How do you do that? I'm also facing the same issues.

Comment: Product -> Perform Action -> Compile "YouFile.swift"

Answer (score 1):

Go to **preferences > general and click in "Continue build after errors"** and you will see more errors immediately. One tip, update your frameworks so that they support Swift 3.0 before you do the migration.

Comment: I've done "Continue build errors" and am left with the same result. Also, most of the frameworks are from iOS 8, but I have yet to update them.

Comment: Not much to do then to do as you have done @FaisalSyed

Comment: So do you recommend I continue to do what I'm doing, and just let my client know that this update will take a while given me having to clean every single file manually?

Comment: This will take a while if you have a lot of files but I would say that most of the problems are probably pretty simple to solve. Let me know if there are any issues and I´ll try to help you with them.

Comment: Yeah most of the problems are pretty trivial, with only a few errors per file being something I have to look into later. I think I just want to solve all the basic errors first in every file, then re-visit each one to solve the more complex errors. Does this sounds like a reasonable way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try look up for some code that makes takes more time to complies with this app [build time analyzer](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode)

You could try this too [improving xcode compile time](https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/improving-swift-compilation-times-from-12-to-2-minutes/?gh_src=4n3gxh1)